# Pass the variable values created in JavaScript to Server Side (Code Behind) in ASP.Net using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need to pass the array value from code behind asp.net C#.

**Aspx Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string ReturnCode=""; //Need to pass value from this side
}
```

Since the data changes dynamically I need to pass the value.

Comment: Maybe a HiddenField will do the work

Comment: use ajax post from javascript to send and get data from server

Comment: Tried with HiddenField it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

**Dirty way.**

Have hidden field in your form.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfArray" runat="server" />
```

In script, write this after your code.

```
$('[id*=hfArray]').val('Task,Hours per Day;Work,11;Eat,2;Commute,2;Watch TV,2;Sleep,7');
```

And in code behind.

```
string rawStr = hfArray.Value;
string[] arrOuter = rawStr.Split(';');
```

And play further.